# What cipher(s) can or should I use for attribute based encryption?

Tags: encryption, abe

What cipher(s) can or should I use for attribute based encryption? Can I use AES for that, or should I use some other, specific cipher(s)?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are asking which encryption scheme is used to encrypt the actual data (file, stream data etc.) while using ABE. To encrypt the data, you can use any block cipher such as AES. Then, use ABE to encrypt block cipher key (AES key).

Comment: Actually, ABE is usually used in a KEM construction, where a group element is randomly chosen and encrypted with ABE. This same group element is hashed to get a key for symmetric encryption. That way, we don't have to think about the sizes of the group element or the key.